# Contains CSS Selector to fill a form with nightwatch / selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors, nightwatch.js

My Problem:

The Page I try to test with NightwatchJS Contains Some Input Fields that have the Same beginning, but a random number is added. I want to Fill the Textfield on the page. Only one with this name is present on the same time.

```
<input id="groupNamec7aed06a-67a1-4780-9cc3-5b985666adb9" class="d-styled-input" data-value-update="keyup" data-bind="value: name" title="">
```

Is the definition of the Field. groupName is every Time the same, but the number changes.

Is there a possibility to use CSS Selector in nightwatch instead of XPATH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
input[id^="groupName"]
```

From [MDN > Attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) :

> `[attr^=value]` : Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and whose first value is prefixed by "value".

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately CSS Selector does not provide such a way. You could use a different CSS Selector to match inputs with an id and get those as a list. Afterwards using `getAttribute('id')` you could do it manually, but this seems like unnecessary effort to me and I'd recommend just using Xpath.

Ofcourse you could try and get a different unique CSS Selector. If it's in a form you could locate the form and use `:nth-child` but if I remember correctly this has limited/no support in IE.

**Edit** Apparently IE9 and later does support `:nth-child`